# Cannot convert JSON response into Java object using JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to convert the http response body which is in JSON format into a Java object using the GSON library, but the object has all attributes equal to null after trying to do so.

My Object class:

```
public class User {
private String username;
private int shipCount;
private int structureCount;
private String joinedAt;
private int credits;

public User(String username, int shipCount, int structureCount, String joinedAt, int credits) {
    this.username = username;
    this.shipCount = shipCount;
    this.structureCount = structureCount;
    this.joinedAt = joinedAt;
    this.credits = credits;
}
```

Plus getters and setters

My attempt at using GSON:

```
        Gson gso = new Gson();

        User userInf = gso.fromJson(response.body(), User.class);
        System.out.println(userInf);
```

The response body is this:

```
{"user":{"username":":chrter","shipCount":0,"structureCount":0,"joinedAt":"2022-04-09T16:52:14.365Z","credits":0}}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If I remember correctly GSON will only set public fields of the object, so you need to make those fields you want to be set to be public

Comment: but I've got getters and setter won't it still do it?

Comment: Getters and setters are not the same thing as the field being public. They don't make fields public either, so no, the only way is to set those fields public

Comment: Still doesn't work with public fields, and I've seen many cases where the fields are private and it works

Comment: Then I don't remember that correctly :D
It also might be the fact that your response object has only one field - "user", which contains the rest of the struct. Then GSON tries to assign the JSON field "user" to any of the fields of the class User. This is not what we want, of course.
Try making another class that has one field named user of type User, and deserialize into that class instead, see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root object of your HTTP response is a JSON object that has only one field - `"user"`. When GSON deserializes the response, it goes through all the fields of the root object and sets them to the corresponding fields of the class you have provided. So it will look for the field `user` in the class `User` and set it to the JSON's data.

Since class `User` has no field `user`, GSON doesn't fill that field. In fact it doesn't fill out any other fields, because there are no other fields in the root object.

To get around this you need to deserialize not the whole response, but only the `user` field of the root object. There are two ways of doing that.

1. Deserialize the root object, and then deserialize the field `user` of that object into the `User` class.

   You can find an example of how to do it in @Saheed's answer. However you should note that it translates JSON string into java objects and then translates java objects back. It might cost you additional time if you're doing it in performance-sensitive area of your program.
2. Create another class which you will deserialize into, which **would** have the field user. It looks like this:

   ```
   class Response {
       public User user;
   };

   class User {
       // ...
   };
   ```

   And then you deserialize like this:

   ```
   Gson gso = new Gson();

   // CHANGE: Deserialize the response and get the user field
   Response response = gso.fromJson(response.body(),Response.class);
   User userInf = response.user;

   System.out.println(userInf);
   ```

Comment: Yea that makes a lot more sense now, I was interpreting the json structure incorrectly and how gson processes it. Thanks heaps

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
public static Map<String, Object> Converter(String str){
    Map<String, Object> map = new Gson().fromJson(str, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
    return map;
}

 Map<String, Object> apiResponse = Converter(response.body().toString());
Map<String, Object> username = Converter(apiResponse.get("user").toString());
System.out.println(username);
```

Tweak it a bit to suit your need

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

```java
    Map<?, ?> map = gson.fromJson(response.body(), Map.class);

    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue());
    }
```